# Same basic WP_Query works on page but not post or custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

```
$applicationQuery = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_status' => 'any' ));

if($applicationQuery->have_posts()){
  $header_text = "Got post (GOOD)";
}
else{
    $header_text = "No post (BAD)";
}
```

This same query, if I use `page` for `post_type` there are results in the query, but if I change `post_type` to `post` or my own `custom_post_type` there's no result. Why? How can I fix this and query my custom post type?

Comment: Are you sure you are passing correct CPT name to post_type argument?
There is no possible reason for your problem except wrong arguments.

Comment: Well I'm absolutely sure I got the name right (copy/pasted). Also, 'post' doesn't work as well.

Comment: Is get_posts() function working?

Comment: What I'm trying is to do get a custom post type authored by the current user with a particular meta value, so get_posts() doesn't seem to help here +_+

Comment: Does change the post_status impact the results ? `Any` will not retrieve the exclude_from_search posts. See more details https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters

Comment: Yes somehow I fixed the problem by changing from 'any' to 'published'. SO doesn't allow me to accept my own answer in 2 days so I can't close it off yet, but thank you guys for your trouble, I really appreciate it ;_;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding `'post_status' => 'published'` into the query array.

**Edit:** The root cause was because the custom posts were programmatically created (not via admin dashboard), and the `post_status` of those posts were set to `published`.

Wordpress doesn't know `published`, by default it only recognize `publish`. The `any` value in the query doesn't actually look for "any" post_status, but "any recognized" post_status.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
        $applicationQuery  = query_posts( array( 'post_type' => array('page') ) );

         while (have_posts()) : the_post();       
                //echo the_title();
         endwhile;
```